# Animation object jam on the rendered video

Tags: rendering, animation-nodes

I have a problem rendering a video when animation nodes are used to animate gears.

In the viewport, the entire animation works correctly without hitches, but after rendering, effect is like the gears "do not have time to spin".

[image]

[image]

The effect of such a tree of animation nodes does not have time to calculate the positions of the objects completely before rendering the frame.

The effect is manifested on all of the following options: 
 - video rendering through UI;

- image rendering through UI;
- rendering through scripts: `blender -b filename.blend -a`
- rendering through the console (https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues/1200 Render Individual Frames)

There is no loop in the node tree, as far as I can see.
[image]

I want to know how to fix this issue. 
I will be appreciated to any help.

File attached

[image]

I use `Blender 2.82` and `animation_nodes_v2_1`

**EDIT:**
Of course, I can use drivers and I understand that this scene is very simple, but I want to figure out why AN is not working correctly.
The fact is that I started studying AN yesterday and this scene is only one of the first samples.
I need to solve this problem with the help of AN for the further learning and creation of more complex scenes using AN without further troubles.

Comment: you could just use drivers or even simpler, constraints for this case. In am not sure about how AN works exactly so maybe there is just an option somewhere...

Comment: Of course, I can use drivers and I understand that this scene is very simple, but I want to figure out why AN is not working correctly.
The fact is that I started studying AN yesterday and this scene is only one of the first samples.
I need to solve this problem with the help of AN for the further learning and creation of more complex scenes using AN without further troubles.